# Jar file not working (filenotfoundexception when running in cmd)

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I know this topic has been up a lot of times and I have been looking at stackoverflow for hours after the sollution but still not working. From Eclipse I can't make my jar-file work when exporting a runnable jar-file. The program is working perfectly in Eclipse when I run it but when I try to open the jar-file the screen is going black for a second then nothing happens. I try to open it in command with java -jar nameoffile.jar and there is filenotfoundexception. This is what it looks like in cmd when I have tried to run it.

Do anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: what is you using to build your jar?

Comment: from eclipse I use  export ->runnable jar file

Comment: Have tried both "package required libraries into generated jar" and "extract required libraries into generated jar"

Comment: i think its complaining about the static resource under folder "songwavs", Can you open your jar with some .zip applcation like winzip, 7zip etc and check if those are present in your jar?

Comment: I will try right away, just a second

Comment: There were no problems opening the jar file in winzip

Comment: can you please attach a image of your project structure in eclipse expanding main and all first subfolders here?

Comment: It would have been better if you would have added the error messages as text and not as image. On a console copying the text isn't that hard.

Comment: I think the sollution was that I was trying to use fileinputstream from the jar, gonna try that and get back, thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you get your resources.

You put your wav file in `src` folder an the try get them using FileInputStream, that's not going to work.

If you put your file into the jar you should access them throug:

`getClass().getResourceAsStream(filepath)`

Something like this.

```
public class LoadFile {
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception  {
        InputStream stream = 
            LoadFile.class.getResourceAsStream("/songwavs/s1_..._.wav");
            AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(stream);
            AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(url);
    }
}
```

That's just an example, the point is that being the resource inside the jar, the ClassLoaders are the tool to get it.

So, inside a non static method you could use:

```
public void myMethod() throws Exception{
    InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/songwavs/s1_..._.wav");
    AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(stream);
}
```

In some circumstance the you need to use the Thread classloader like this:

```
public void myMethod2() throws Exception{
    InputStream stream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/songwavs/s1_..._.wav");
    AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(stream);
}
```

Then you can put read your file both when running from eclipse or from the jar.

Much more could be said about how to package an application and deploy it, but that's just a start.

Comment: Ok. But instead of changing the program, pretty much code there is a export jar file choice "copy required libraries into a subfolder next to the generated jar file", maybe that could work?

Comment: No, it won't, beacaue FileInputStream reads files, while an entry in a jar file is not a file, you should deploy your src dir along with your app, and put it inside the working dir when you run the application.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help! Gonna change my program tonight with using  LoadFile.class.getResourceAsStream("/songwavs/s1_..._.wav"); and see if it works. I get back later tonight

Comment: Your help made the program work outside Eclipse. Thanks a lot